# Clarification regarding traditional interpreter, compiler and JIT compiler/interpreter

Tags: java, compilation, interpreter, jit

I'm learning Java and the following things are a bit confusing for me. What I understood is:

- **Java Compiler** → The Java compiler just converts `.java` programs into `.class` files, which means converting our source code into bytecode (it is a list of op codes for the virtual machine (JVM) which makes Java platform-independent).
- **Java Interpreter** → merely "interprets" the code and *does not* transform it into native machine code. It executes each and every instruction of the byte code one-by-one as a command and carries it out, regardless how many time the same instruction occurs. That's why it's slow and Java introduces the JIT concept.
- **JIT Compiler** → This also comes into play at execution time. The JIT compiler is able to improve performance by caching results of blocks of code that have been *translated* – compared to simply re-evaluating every line or operand in the bytecode each time it occurs.

Now I have several questions:

1. As my physical processor understands only native machine code, how does a Java program get executed using the JVM's interpreter? The interpreter doesn't convert bytecode to native machine code. Until and unless someone places the machine code into memory, the physical processor won't be able to execute it.
2. Supposing that somehow, the interpreter also converts bytecode to native machine code then a "block of code execution with caching (JIT) and line-by-line execution (interpreter)" is the only thing that differentiates the JIT and the interpreter?
3. If, at execution time, a JIT compiler translates bytecode to native machine code (for executing the program), why doesn't Java use ahead-of-time compilation? After generating the JVM-dependent bytecode (which in turn makes Java platform-independent), we could bring it to the target machine where we want to execute it and just translate it to native machine code (creating an `.exe` or `.out` file as is the case with C compilation). This could be possible because we have a specific JVM on every system. This would be much faster than using JIT compilation as it takes some time compiling and loading the program. It will still be platform-independent by just distributing bytecode (generated before the final translation from bytecode to machine code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: Take all of this with a grain of salt; it's pretty oversimplified.

1: You are correct in that the computer itself doesn't understand the code, which is why the JVM itself is needed. Let's pretend `XY` means "add the top two elements on the stack and push the result". The JVM would then be implemented something like this:

```
for(byte bytecode : codeToExecute) {
    if (bytecode == XX) {
        // ...do stuff...
    } else if (bytecode == XY) {
        int a = pop();
        int b = pop();
        push(a+b);
    } else if (bytecode == XZ) {
        // ...do stuff...
    } // ... and so on for each possible instruction ...
}
```

The JVM has, in the computer's native machine code, implemented each individual instruction and essentially looks up each chunk of bytecode for how to execute it. By JITting the code, you can achieve large speedups by omitting this interpretation (i.e. looking up how each and every instruction is supposed to be handled). That, and optimization.

2: The JIT doesn't really run the code; everything is still run inside the JVM. Basically, the JIT translates a chunk of bytecode into machine code when appropriate. When the JVM then comes across it, it thinks "Oh hey, this is already machine code! Sweet, now I won't have to carefully check each and every byte of this as the CPU understands it on its own! I'll just pump it through and everything will magically work on its own!".

3: Yes, [it is possible](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/295) to pre-compile code in that way to avoid the early overhead of interpretation and JITting. However, by doing so, you lose something very valuable. You see, when the JVM interprets the code, it also keeps statistics about everything. When it then JITs the code, it knows how often different parts are used, allowing it to optimize it where it matters, making the common stuff faster at the expense of the rare stuff, yielding an overall performance gain.

Comment: 1.Here by JVM you mean interpreter or a combination of some other things?
2.You mean JIt makes task of interpreter much faster but still interpretation is needed after JITing?
3.How JIT compiler can make better optimazation?A traditional (B-code to m-code) compiler can do better optimization as it has full code available before execution.(GCC can do a very good optimization in case of C/C++)

Comment: 1) The JVM basically means "that which runs a Java program", which INCLUDES interpreting but also other stuff. 2) Yes and no. Even if the class MyClass has been JITted, the rest of the program might still be interpreted. As such, the JVM still needs to be there to handle transitions between interpreted and JITted code. 3) I don't know any examples off-hand. I've forgotten exactly what data is collected, so I have a hard time thinking of a hypothetical scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your help.but I'm still curious to know why jit concept was adopted if there were traditional way of compilation and optimization which could support both portability and good performance.

Comment: @DeepankarSingh There wasn't. Compiled code is always faster than interpreted code. The point of the HotSpot JVM is to find the bits of the interpreted code that are taking the time and compile only those.

Answer (score 1):

1. At the end, even in an interpreter the machine code that is equivalent to a bytecode instruction gets run, it just happens more indirectly. Think of it like a piano. A CPU is like a player piano. A compiler punches holes into a strip of paper, which you then run on the piano. Using an interpreter is essentially placing a human-like machine in front of the piano who reads the sheet-music and pushes the keys on the piano. In the end, the same chords sound out, but there's an additional level of indirection.
2. Yes. Pretty much.
3. As you mention, Java was touted as "compile once, run anywhere". So the bytecode is an important feature to deliver that promise. The reason why it doesn't get compiled when it arrives on your computer is a practical one: Compiling is slow. Usually, it happens at the software developer's. If every Java application you launch was compiled the first time, you would be waiting a while.

   Since most programs do not get run completely (there are branches that aren't taken, menu items you never choose etc.), it is usually faster to compile the parts that are needed, as they are needed. It also saves on disk space, as otherwise you'd have two copies of every program on your computer.

That said, you're not the first one to wonder about this, and in fact some people write their programs in Java, but use a *compiler* to actually generate executables from them. Java(-to-native) compilers exist, they're just not the common use case, because many people at that point use portable C or C++.

Comment: 1.your first analogy went over my head.
2.if they're pretty much same then JVM doesn't have to do any interpretation after JITing the code?
3.though traditional compilation of code is slow(than JITing) but once,after compiling,executable can be run as many times as we want much faster than JITing the code every time.So having dual copy and one time compilation would be more advantageous sacrifice.

Comment: A "player piano" is an automatic piano. You see it in some western movies (the kind with cowboys, not generally western). It has ticker-tape-like roll of hole-ounched paper in it that makes it play a certain song.

Comment: @DeepankarSingh Like a music box.